# how to set PEM file and access it in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: ssl, gitlab, openssl, gitlab-ci, pem

I am building a GitLab pipeline to check if all the integration tests are successful. But I am getting a "self-signed certificate in certificate chain" error and am not able to connect the third-party URL. How can I pass the .pem file into the GitLab-ci.yml file?

[image]

Thanks in advance